# the .xkm file loading error

Tags: ati, 14.04

After I install the graphic cards driver,when I log in the system the error below happen . 
Graphic cards: ATI Mobility HD 5650 + Intel 
when boot the screen can display the login screen , after I type in the password and press enter this error happen,at this time I can only see the wallpaper and the mouse pointer

```
[ 290.376] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.1 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 290.395] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[ 290.500] (II) XKB: generating xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-992DCD2811F9928D990F91F3229E52A1EC62B72A.xkm
[ 290.518] (EE) Error loading keymap /var/lib/xkb/server-992DCD2811F9928D990F91F3229E52A1EC62B72A.xkm
```

Comment: What graphics card driver? What graphics card? Where do you see this error? Is that from `~/.xsession-errors`? What happens afterwards?

Comment: my computer has two cards,ATI 5650+Intel, I install the ATI griver.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the model of your card, how you installed the drivers, which version you installed, and most importantly, where/when you see that error and whether it causes any problems.

Comment: after log in , the screen only display the wallpaper and the mouse pointer, the Xorg.o.log file display the error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. You can then ping the user who asked for the information by leaving a comment and including a `@` before their username. For example, to ping me: `@terdon`.

Comment: @terdon I have edit the question